# Operar elementos de um array

Tags: javascript, array

Galera é possível operar elementos de um array em JavaScript sem a necessidade de utilizar uma estrutura de repetição como for ou while.
Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenha um array com 10 elementos e desejo pega cada elemento e dividi-los por 2, sem utilizar os comandos for ou while é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer dividir numericamente cada elemento do *array* por 2, então sim, é possível fazer isso sem o laço de repetição (e até é recomendado fazer).

A solução é utilizar a `Array.prototype.map`, que executa uma expressão para cada um dos elementos. Alinhada às *arrow functions*, o código fica bastante simples:

```
const half = [2, 4, 6, 8].map(it => it/2);  // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HardSpryHorseshoecrab)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, é uma Lambda Expression? Bem parecido com o java.